# colnames(df[1,]) puts numbers instead of row 1 as colname

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`. When I print the first row I get

```
> print(df[1,])
V2         V3         V4         V5        
A          B          C          D
```

I want A,B, etc to be the colnames so I do

```
colnames(df) <- df[1,]
```

However, when I print the colnames I now get

```
> print(colnames(df))
[1] "1101" "852"  "782"  "534" 

        V2          V3         V4        
        A           B          C  
col1    48.6        2          0.2           
col2    68.7        3.4        0.3               
col3    34.2        2.7        0.5
```

How should I set the colnames?

Comment: Try `colnames(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))`. Your columns seem to be `factor`.

Comment: And `class(df[1, ])` shows that it's a one-row data frame - hence the `unlist` in the above comment.

Comment: more importantly, where did you get `df` from? any data reader worth its weight in code has an option to specify lines to skip and whether/where to expect a header

Comment: @nicola that did not work @MichaelChirico I get a `list` through Renjin and then I do `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(expressionTable), nrow=length(unlist(expressionTable[1]))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gregor and nicola have picked up your columns appear to be factors and colnames() needs a vector input not a dataframe, try the following:

```
colnames(df) <- as.vector(t(df[1,]))
```

t() transposes the vector to a single column matrix, as.vector() then drops the second dimension.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = factor("a"),x2 = factor("b"),x3 = factor("c"),x4 = factor("d"))
colnames(df) <- as.vector(t(df[1,]))
df <- df[-1,] # removes the first row
```